# AngularJS Directive not rendering ui-bootstrap attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, slickgrid

I have an angular directive wrapper around a 3rd party grid library: Slickgrid. For some of the cells, I want to use the ui-bootstrap tooltip directive so I add the tooltip attribute to those cells. When I inspect the element in question:

```
<div class="slick-cell l0 r0 active" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip="TOOLTIP">...</div>
```

But I never see the tooltip being rendered. If I put the tooltip attributes on another directive in the HTML file, it works. So I have verified that all the dependencies are in place and tooltips should work.

Is there a reason why Angular doesn't detect the ui-bootstrap attributes on the html that slickgrid spits out?

Comment: Did you inject 'ui-bootstrap'?

Comment: Yes, the module definition that the directive is a member of contains 'ui-bootstrap'.

Comment: ok, can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a priority issue, here is directive docs for long version.

> priority - When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

Comment: Your comment sent me in the right direction. I also had to recompile the node that got modified. So once I $compile(element) AND set a higher priority, everything worked as expected.